# detecting multitouch longpress event using rxjs

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, rxjs

Been playing around with rxjs. I find it really good, but it really took some time to get my head around it.
Here's a little one I can't solve, so I'm looking for some insight.

Consider a multitouch interface where for each touchstart/touchmove/touchend you would have as params an object with {id:, x:x, y:y, t:t, current_pointers: }

I would like an observable that would trigger an event for each down pointer after 1500 ms unless touchmove or touchup happens for that pointer.

For a single touch it's straightforward, you would just takeUntil touch move or touchup, but how would you use takeUntil when the id of the pointer is within the first observable in the chain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to flatten the touches array so you can treat the touches individually.  Here's the basic idea, using the Rx-jQuery bindings.  I've not tested it so it might be a bit buggy:

```
var flattenTouches = function (ev) {
    return ev.changedTouches.map(function(t) { return { ev: ev, touch: t }; });
};
var starts = $element.bindAsObservable("touchstart")
    .selectMany(function (ev) { return Rx.Observable.fromArray(flattenTouches(ev)); });
var moves = $element.bindAsObservable("touchmove")
    .selectMany(function (ev) { return Rx.Observable.fromArray(flattenTouches(ev)); })
    .publish().refCount(); // to prevent multiple subscriptions
var ends = $element.bindAsObservable("touchend")
    .selectMany(function (ev) { return Rx.Observable.fromArray(flattenTouches(ev)); })
    .publish().refCount(); // to prevent multiple subscriptions

var moveOrEnds = Rx.Observable.mergeObservable(moves, ends);
var timer = Rx.Observable.timer(1500);

var longpresses = starts
    .selectMany(function (start) {
        var thisPointerMovesOrEnds = movesOrEnds.where(function(t) {
            return t.touch.identifier === start.touch.identifier;
        });
        return timer
            .takeUntil(thisPointerMovesOrEnds)
            .select(start);
    });

longpresses.subscribe(function (t) {
    console.log("longpress", t.touch.pageX, t.touch.pageY, t.touch.identifier);
});
```

Comment: Thx, what i was missing was the timer bit, i tended  to use the touchdown again when i should have used timer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is what I find difficult with RxJS.

According to the specs, timer with only one argument produces only one event.  Assuming this works, how?  What actually starts the timer?  How are multiple events generated?

Comment: @bnieland Timer creates an observable that will produce only one event *after you subscribe*.  Each time you subscribe, you'll start a new timer which will produce an event later.  The act of subscribing is what starts a timer and every subscription is independent of every other subscription. Timer is what is known as a "cold observable".  Read about "cold" and "hot" observables to get a better handle on this.

Comment: I reproduced this code in this codepen (http://codepen.io/brettnieland/pen/rxJReM?editors=0010), but it always fires, regardless of the hold time (FYI: I am using chromes touch emulation).